# Lazy Loading PDF

Tags: java, performance, pdf, lazy-loading

I would like to implement lazy loading PDFs. Going through the forums we need to make make the PDF documents as 'linearized' and It will load first few pages quickly because it store page references in the start of the file.  Will this resolve below problem as well.

There is separate charge for data transfer in AWS. Users want to see only first pages, But our system has to download entire PDF document that may be huge file. So we have to pay more money. If  linearized PDF solves how to implement in Java technoglogy while download

Answer (score 0):

The way a linearized PDF is processed by a PDF reader is implementation dependent, but I dare to say that in all cases, it is very likely that the reader will just continue to download the rest of the file in the background after showing the first page. The goal of linearization is not to prevent the rest of the file from being downloaded.

An alternative could be for you to split the file in sections and provide bookmarks that point to external PDF documents that will allow navigating through all the sections.